# In what ways humans could adapt to communicate if there was no languages at all?

Tags: society, culture, communication, language

Assuming language is a barrier when it comes to socializing. How would people socialize?

How would they be mean to each other?

How would they sound at all?

When I say language, I mean the code, the sense to which our mind interpret things.

Comment: What definition of language are you using? And would humans still be capable of language? If they were, the languages  were simply lost somehow, humans would simply generate a new language from gestures and vocalizations.

Comment: People spend so much time texting each other nowadays that sometimes it seems that speech is obsolete. *Note: Social commentary! Social commentary!*

Comment: Do you mean no verbal language? Or would you count sign-language, writing, and art as well?

Comment: Yes please elaborate on what you mean by 'no language'.

Comment: @EmmettR. sign-language , writing and art eventually interpret to some sort of thing (language) , to which human mind reads. what do you think ?

Comment: Sorry, but cats and dogs can **both** interpret human actions and voices to understand our intentions **and** communicate vocally or with actions their own intentions. They usually do not have much to communicate beyond "Give food, now, you slave!" or "Let me out" but they do not really seem to have problems with the basic concept of communicating. If no language means no grammar or sentence structures, cats and dogs would probably be a good model for your answer. Effective intelligence would also be similar, I think.

Comment: Why would anyone want to socialize. The whole point of language is to share ideas (using a common code verbal, sign, gesture, written, expression cues, pattern recognition). To socialize is to share ideas using a common code.

Comment: Try going abroad to a place where you don't understand the language at all. You will find you can communicate well enough to survive. People who have something to say will always find a way. Think of stroke victims who communicate by blinking.

Comment: If humans couldn't communicate then we'd be long extinct

Answer (score 3):

Already today, a huge amount of our communication is done through what is called social cues. Some of them are verbal (intonation, fluctuation, volume...) and other are non-verbal (eye gaze, body posture, gestures, facial expressions...).

There is an entire field of study, social sciences, that tries to investigate how people "socialize", to use your own term. To these scientist, communication is done through a broad range of ways, some can be called language and some can't but the limit is blurred when you look at it closely.

People draw stories from the stars, from music... in the same way you can "see" a face in three dots on a piece of paper. You are wired to use anything for communication.

I believe your question cannot be answered.

Comment: I would add that, according to the broadest definitions of language, 'sending and receiving signals,' as Sajjad seems to ask about, even creatures without a nervous system can communicate through chemical means. A creature that could not process any form of signal whatsoever would have to be completely cut off from its environment, or more inert than a typical plant, which can produce chemical and visual markers to communicate with other species.